# Do integers occupy less space as keys in a java HashMap compared to strings?

Tags: java, string, hash, hashmap

Let's say I have a `HashMap<String, Integer>` with keys being words and values being their frequency in a corpus. Does it save memory to replace words with some integer (e.g. `"hello"` is represented by `1`) and instead create a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`? In general, integers occupy less space than strings but then I don't know if that can apply to keys of a HashMap since keys go through a hash function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: hashcode of an Intger in java is equal to the value, so I would assume that it's more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the `HashMap` is concerned, there is no difference in memory usage when replacing `String` with `Integer`.

This is because `HashMap` stores the reference values of the key and value in its KV Pair, and instead of referencing `String` objects, the key will refer to `Integer` objects.

For all intents and purposes, the hashing of `Integer` objects and `String` objects, do not have any impact on the HashMap's storage capabilities.

Comment: This is all true 'as far as the HashMap is concerned', but that wasn't his question.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be his question, @EJP. Your answer is irrelevant. Java objects (which both Integer and String are) are passed by (and maintained as) references.

Comment: I was going off of the sentence: "In general, integers occupy less space than strings but then I don't know if that can apply to keys of a HashMap since keys go through a hash function." My response was to say that the keys of a HashMap don't get influenced by the size of the key type since it is just a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. An Integer is smaller than a String even if the String is empty, because an 'int' is smaller than a reference to 'char[]' plus more 'ints' for the offset, length, and hash code. And if you use Integer.valueOf() there is also caching, but then there is also String caching via the constant pool of course.

However unless you have millions of entries the effect is negligible, so you should whatever keys suit the program.